# Simple custom attributes on posts

Tags: customization, custom-field

I'm working on a site which will have a dozen of menus. There will be a subnavigation widget below the header. My client wants his content writers to be able to select which menu would show up in the subnavigation widget.

I've created a simple meta box with a drop down which shows all the navigation menus the wordpress instance currently has. I only need to save the content writer's choice and use it to show the current menu inside the sub navigation.

I'm looking for a simple way to do this. I know there are things like advacned custom fields, but that plugin seems over kill for such small requirements. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by storing value in post meta table